# Add constraint PK using index tablespace

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to run this code:

```
ALTER TABLE OPS.F4111 ADD CONSTRAINT F4111_PK PRIMARY KEY ( ILUKID ) USING INDEX 
OPS.F4111_0 
USING INDEX TABLESPACE OPS;
```

But getting an error:
*01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"*

What is wrong with the code?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `USING INDEX` twice. I think that you want:

```
ALTER TABLE OPS.F4111 ADD CONSTRAINT F4111_PK PRIMARY KEY (ILUKID) 
USING INDEX TABLESPACE OPS;
```